# Javascript FormData indexes change when reading results in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When posting files and data, the indexes of the inputs change in a weird way. With current HTML inputs:

```
<input type="text" id="field_4155" class="form-control" name="Form[46][mc][22][32][187][name]" value="Test123">
<input type="file" id="field_4156" class="form-control" name="Form[46][mc][22][32][187][media]" multiple="multiple">
```

When submitting these HTML fields with:

```
    //formdata object maken
    var formData = new FormData( $('#form_113')[0] );
    $.ajax({
        url: document.location.href,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data)
        {
        }
    });
```

will result in:

```
Array
(
    [Form] => Array
        (
            [46] => Array
                (
                    [mc] => Array
                        (
                            [22] => Array
                                (
                                    [32] => Array
                                        (
                                            [187] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [name] => Test123
                                                )
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [Form] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [46] => Array
                        (
                            [mc] => Array
                                (
                                    [22] => Array
                                        (
                                            [32] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [187] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [media] => Merge-SPSS.doc
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )
        )
)
```

as you can see the indexes change, but why?

Answer (score 0):

Of course after i post it, i see why.. (and silly of me..).

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
    (
    )

    [type] => Array
    (
    )

    [tmp_name] => Array
    (
    )

    [error] => Array
    (
    )

    [size] => Array
    (
    )
)
```